# Cypress aliased variable is inaccessible

Tags: cypress

After I upgraded to Cypress 12, this problem started to happen. The only update to my code was upgrading cypress. The problem is that when I attempt to access an alias, some were accessible and others were not. In my test, I have aliased these two variables `noRows` and `role_0`

[image]
[image]

When I attempted to access them, `noRows` was accessible, but `role_0` was not, and the test failed due to this.

This had no problem [image]

But this had [image] as the test kept trying to access it but was never able to do it.

This is where I alias them:

```js
cy.get('#role_0').invoke('text').invoke('trim').as(`role_0`);
cy.wrap(index + 1).as('noRows');
```

And later in this test I attempt to access them:

```js
cy.get('@noRows').then(noRows => {
    cy.get(`#row`).should('have.length', noRows);
});
cy.get(`@role_0`).should('eq', shipment_ST);
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the code where this issue is occurring, as that will be more helpful than the screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be due to the revamp of the alias behaviour in version 12.

Prior to 12, an alias would only try to re-evaluate when a "detached from DOM" error was found.

After 12 it re-evaluates all the time, but it introduced a breaking change if your test relies on the initial value.

This doesn't exactly sound like the problem you are describing, but it's worth trying the "fix" anyway.

See [Changelog 12.4.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-4-0)

> The `.as` command now accepts an options argument, allowing an alias to be stored as type "query" or "static" value. This is stored as "query" by default. Addresses #25173.

So in your test, use `.as('role_0', { type: 'static' })` to make it work more like a fixed variable rather than a retriable query.